# Best way to include dynamic tables (with merge option) using JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext, dynamic-reports

I'm facing the following problem: I have to include dynamic tables (with possible cell-merging) in a Jasper report designed with iReport (it would be a huge effort to change our report generation tool now).

Basically what I need is to include a html-table structure (with free cell-merging, using rowspan and colspan) inside a Jasper report, and as far as I know there is no native way to include that kind of dynamic table within a Jasper report (I've tried the "HTML Component" but apparently it has many problems with stretching so I discarded it).

Example (complex table style that might be generated): [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SjHt.png)

PdfPTable (from iText) matches exactly what I need (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/table.html): dynamic table solution with rowspan and colspan support. The problem is that I can't include a PDF (generated with iText) into the original Jasper report.

The best I could think by now is: (1) convert iText generated table (PDF) to image and (2) insert it as image on the original report, when generating the DataSource. Alternatively I could try to find a html-to-image converter and repeat step (2).

However, I'd rather find a cleaner solution. Anyone can help me suggesting a better option? Am I wrong by assuming that there is no native solution for what I'm trying to accomplish? Perhaps is it achievable somehow using DynamicJasper?

Thank you.

PS: I've searched exhaustively for similar questions/answers but I could only find outdated answers, referring to old Jasper versions; that's why I'm creating a new question (sorry if I did it wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem could be solved by dynamicReport api, It will allow you to create any kind of dynamic headers or contents by java code only and also a functionality to export its jasper files.

So what you can do is create your dynamic content using dynamicReports and export jasper of that content of specific height or width in your classpath and use that file in your iReport designed Jasper files.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm not sure if DynamicReport has any cell merge/unmerge native support (I don't think so), but I guess it can be somehow achieved by mixing Tables and Subreports, right?

I ended up using a "html to image" library to generate the tables, then I inserted them into my main Jasper report. It worked although I would rather had find a more elegant solution.

Comment: hmm...good, that you got your solution.
In dynamic report, you would be able to set dimension and style of a cell on run time using horizontalList. So it would be totally dynamic, can be generated as per requirement by java code only.